# error while creating jar file

Tags: applet

problem is occurs while creating jar file "java exception occurred" that's why i have added zip file is it sounds correct or not what i have to do can you please tell me?

Comment: Honestly, we can't help you, because you haven't given enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Add exception details and executed command to your question.

Answer (score 0):

to create jar file in java eclipse

1)write a java coding in eclipse 2)run in java platform 3)click to file->export->runnable jar file->next->launch configuration(project name)->export destination(destination folder)->finish 4)open the destination folder 5).jar extension file is nothing but your jar file